# Share Point Custom Display Form not displaying data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365-developer

In order to display the list column values in view mode, I have created a new custom form with type "Display Form" using Share-point Designer. When I open the file, I can see the code as (Attached the sample code only for reference), but when opened the browser using the URL `https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/***/subsite/Lists/Employee%20List/CustomDisplayForm.aspx?ID=14` I cannot see any data in the form.

```
   <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>Title</nobr>
            </H3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>First Name</nobr>
            </H3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
            <xsl:value-of select="@First_x0020_Name"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Can someone help me on this.

DataSource Code:

```
<DataSources>
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentType&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Employee Content type&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" UseInternalName="True" UseServerDataFormat="True"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://testsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/test/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{54AD5A3F-3309-47DD-BD8E-E32C90E05CED}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </SelectParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://testsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/test/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{54AD5A3F-3309-47DD-BD8E-E32C90E05CED}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://testsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/test/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{54AD5A3F-3309-47DD-BD8E-E32C90E05CED}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </InsertParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://testsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/test/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{54AD5A3F-3309-47DD-BD8E-E32C90E05CED}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
</DataSources>
```

Updated full code

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="Employee List" ViewFlag="8" ViewContentTypeId="" Default="FALSE" ListName="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" ListId="3aca5686-58d3-4e36-ac8f-0d7812940950" PageType="PAGE_EDITFORM" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" Title="Employee List" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_2dfdb5ea_8282_4460_9480_e98c619f0bbd" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{2DFDB5EA-8282-4460-9480-E98C619F0BBD}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><DataSources>
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentType&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Employee Employee Content type&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" UseInternalName="True" UseServerDataFormat="True"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </SelectParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </InsertParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
</DataSources>
<Xsl>






<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
    <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">&apos;</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="UserID" />
    <xsl:param name="WPPropertyBinding" />
    <xsl:param name="LogonUser"/>
    <xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%" class="ms-vb" valign="top">
                            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/staticrefresh.gif" id="ManualRefresh" border="0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" alt="Click here to refresh the dataview."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">ListForm</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
        <div>
            <span id="part1">
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </table>
            </span>
            <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton1"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">

            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowedit"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ms-descriptiontext" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Edit" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowedit">
        <xsl:param name="Pos" select="position()"/>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <xsl:if test="@PaymentStatus = 'Demo JB'">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                    <nobr>Title<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                                    </nobr>
                                </H3>
                            </td>
                            <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                                <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
                                <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>PaymentStatus</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="PaymentStatus" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@PaymentStatus')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="PaymentStatus" ControlMode="Edit"/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
                        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                            <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                            <script>
          var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
          if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
          document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';
        </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="99" class="ms-vb">
                                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   </Xsl>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<ParameterBindings>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="weburl" Location="None" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="LogonUser" Location = "ServerVariable(LOGON_USER)" />
         <ParameterBinding Name="WPPropertyBinding" Location="Control(@Nationality)"  DefaultValue="asssss" />
     </ParameterBindings>
</WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an item with ID = 14 in your list?

Comment: @MarceloEspinosa Yes the QueryString ID = 14 has values in the list. If I open the same ID using custom Editor Form the values are binded properly

Comment: can you post your data source code?

Comment: @MarceloEspinosa This is what you have asked for correct?

Comment: Have you set your list to display items using the custom form you've created using SharePoint Designer? check the image: http://imgur.com/a/4mot0

Comment: @MarceloEspinosa You meant to say whether I have set as default right? Yes. I have set the display form as Default.

Comment: What about your ID parameter bindings? <ParameterBindings>
   <ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>

Comment: @MarceloEspinosa In the URL I am specifying ID so the ListItemld would be taken from QueryString.

Comment: Can you post all your webpart code? If the ID was not in the list you should take the error:  "The item does not exist in http://yoursitename/Lists/customview.aspx?ID=600. It may have been deleted or renamed by another user."

Comment: @ThalesChemenian Can you please let me know what you refer by Web part Code. Yes, if the ID doesn't exists in the system it throw the error as you  mentioned.

Comment: All your WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart tag

Comment: @ThalesChemenian, Updated the question with full code. Please have a look.

Comment: Try deleting your form and re creating and customizing it again.

Comment: @MarceloEspinosa Checked that as well.  Its not working too.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for all the code that you have pasted, and the problem that you have described, your issue must be:

```
<xsl:if test="@PaymentStatus = 'Demo JB'"></xsl:if>
```

You said it's not returning any data, make sure if the ID of item is correct and if the Column `PaymentStatus` of this item is equal to `"Demo JB"`.

If you want to list the items even if the column `PaymentStatus` is different than `"Demo JB"` just delete your `<xsl:if>` tag.

Comment: My ID is valid and is available in the List. The condition you have mentioned is what I have also given, but even if the value is there for Payment Status column is Demo JB, its not entering into the if condition.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that the the item available in the list with the ID specified in the query string. by default if you view it from the SharePoint Designer using the **View in Browser** option it will load the first item from the list.

Comment: Yes the QueryString ID = 14 has values in the list. If I open the same ID using custom Editor Form the values are binded properly

Comment: make this form as a default display form of the list and try opening it

Comment: Still the same. Values are blank